# Get button name in two different forms in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 different forms which are form1 and form2. For the form1, I have 4 different buttons with the name btnSet1,btnSet2,btnSet3,btnSet4 and each button of form1 will link to the same form2

**Form1**

```
Private Sub btnSet1_Click(sender As Object, 
   e As EventArgs) Handles btnSet1.Click, btnSet2.Click, btnSet3.Click, btnSet4.Click
    Select True
        Case sender Is btnSet1
            form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case sender Is btnSet2
            form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case sender Is btnSet3
            form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Case sender Is btnSet4
            form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
    End Select
End Sub
```

For my form2, I have 4 more buttons. So how do I get my previous form1 button name(btnSet1/2/3/4) to my current form2 and write into form1.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click,Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click

If (sender Is form1.btnSet1) Then 
     'How do I get the form1 btnSet1/2/3/4 if user click any button in form1

                Select Case True 
                    Case sender Is Button1 'form2 clicked button action
                        'bla...
                    Case sender Is Button2
                        'bla...
                    Case sender Is Button3
                       'bla...
                    Case sender Is Button4
                       'bla...
                End Select
ElseIf (sender Is form1.btnSet2) Then
                Select Case True 
                    Case sender Is Button1 'form2 clicked button action
                        'bla...
                    Case sender Is Button2
                        'bla...
                    Case sender Is Button3
                       'bla...
                    Case sender Is Button4
                       'bla...
                End Select
End If
```

Comment: I *think* the answer is that form1 is not going to catch event raised by buttons on form2 - the question is pretty murky.  That forst clock could be reduced to 2 lines of code since the buttons all do the same thing

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry about that. I'm totally new in VB. Actually I'm doing for the food ordering. For example, Set 1,2,3,4 will link to the same form. When it goes to form2, I need to select less ice,no ice,etc(button) for selected set in form1 and write into listbox.

For example:
When user click on set 3 in form1 and select special order(no ice,less ice) in form2, it will write into listbox like Set 3/bla/less ice in form1 listbox

Comment: You could create a function in form2 to store that value. Right before the .Show you would call that function, ex: form2.SetButtonSender(1) _ form2.Show()

Comment: @the_lotus Is it possible way to create something like Form1.btnSet1.Click in the handling event instead of Handles Button1.Click,Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click

Comment: @LeeLasc I don't understand what you are trying to do with that comment...

Comment: @the_lotus Ok..I will make it more understandable. 
Let's say we have 2 forms: form1 and form2. Form1 consists of 4 buttons. When user clicked on button1, it will show it is button1 and so on.

Comment: Display Form2 as a **dialog** via `ShowDialog ()`, and set a Property in it that Form1 can retrieve afterwards.

Comment: I think we are a little confused, I know I am. Are you asking to know in Form2, which button you clicked in Form1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example I would do something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim oForm2 As New Form2

    Private Sub btnSet1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSet1.Click, btnSet2.Click, btnSet3.Click, btnSet4.Click
        Select Case True
            Case sender Is btnSet1
                oForm2.oCallingButton = Me.btnSet1
                oForm2.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Case sender Is btnSet2
                oForm2.oCallingButton = Me.btnSet2
                oForm2.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Case sender Is btnSet3
                oForm2.oCallingButton = Me.btnSet3
                oForm2.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Case sender Is btnSet4
                oForm2.oCallingButton = Me.btnSet4
                oForm2.Show()
                Me.Hide()
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Public oCallingButton As Button

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click
        If (oCallingButton Is Form1.btnSet1) Then
            Select Case True
                Case sender Is Button1 'form2 clicked button action
                    'bla...
                Case sender Is Button2
                    'bla...
                Case sender Is Button3
                    'bla...
                Case sender Is Button4
                    'bla...
            End Select
        ElseIf (oCallingButton Is Form1.btnSet2) Then
            Select Case True
                Case sender Is Button1 'form2 clicked button action
                    'bla...
                Case sender Is Button2
                    'bla...
                Case sender Is Button3
                    'bla...
                Case sender Is Button4
                    'bla...
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Instead of the massive case statement, why not... `oForm2.oCallingButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)`?

Comment: Just trying to solve the original problem based on the given example code. I totally agree with you though but don't want to confuse the op too much since he already said he was new to VB.Net.

Comment: This is the result I want and it solves my problem. I will further research the DirectCast since this project I was created for my self-learning purposes. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @LeeLasc, if you come back to read this, kindly accept an answer so that others will know which answer you found most useful. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: @Joeu, Done. Thanks again for your answer and your warmest welcome! =D

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to solve this. First of all, let's get the generic `sender` object back to a button...

```
Dim ButtonSet = DirectCast(sender, Button)
```

#### Constructor

Add a parameter to Form2's constructor

```
Public Class Form2(ButtonSet as Button)
End Class
```

Then use it when you instantiate Form2

```
Dim SecondForm = New Form2(ButtonSet)
SecondForm.Show()
```

Pros: Quick 'n dirty

Cons: Assumes Form2 will always be called with a button set. Also breaks anywhere else you use Form2.

#### Static State

Create a 3rd class that will hold pertinent information.

```
Public Class SharedInfo
    Public Static Property ButtonSet As Button
End Class
```

Then, in Form1 `SharedInfo.ButtonSet = ButtonSet`. Form2 can read `SharedInfo.ButtonSet` any time it wants to.

Pros: Extensible. You can keep adding forms (or variables) and they'll all see the same state.

Cons: Dangerously close to Global Variables, can make it easy to write code that is too tightly coupled. Possible to launch Form2 before the state has been set.

#### With a Dialog

If you're only opening Form2 to grab additional information, a dialog may be the way to go. Dialogs are used for Colour pickers, file save/open, etc... [@Idle_Mind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27630545/156755) sums this one up nicely.

Pros: Modal (Prevents Form1 from being modified while Form2 is visible)
Cons: Possibly overkill

#### With properties / other methods

Similar to the dialog approach except that the window isn't modal (you can use both windows at the same time).

Add the following to Form2

```
Public Property ButtonSet As Button
```

Then from Form1

```
Dim SecondForm = New Form2()
Form2.ButtonSet = ButtonSet
Form2.Show()
```

Pros: Readable, explicit, not hard to extend

Cons: Properties can be changed at any time. Is Form2 going to handle the ButtonSet changing? or only check once on startup? Depends on how exactly you want to use the Button Set in Form2. If you're only going to read it once on load, don't use properties.

Comment: Clear explanation for each method. It needs to handle value in my Form2.

[Joeu's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627281/get-button-name-in-two-different-forms-in-vb/27630090#27630090) is the result that I wanted. Thank you so much

Comment: My pleasure. In case it helps... If you only want to know which button is pressed, there's no reason to pass the whole object. Consider using a String or [better] an Enum to pass values around. Far less memory usage and cleaner code. Either way, welcome to SO. See you around

Answer (score 0):

I ~think~ I understand what you're after...

Here's my Form1:

[image: Menu Form1]

Here's my Form2:

[image: Menu Form2]

Code for Form1:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub DrinkSelection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCoke.Click, btnPepsi.Click, btnRootBeer.Click, btnSprite.Click
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Dim f2 As New Form2(btn.Text)
        If f2.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(btn.Text & ", " & f2.Selection)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Code for Form2:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private _Selection As String = ""

    Public ReadOnly Property Selection
        Get
            Return _Selection
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Drink As String)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Text = "Customize " & Drink
    End Sub

    Private Sub SelectionMade_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNoIce.Click, btnLessIce.Click, btnNormalIce.Click, btnMoreIce.Click
        _Selection = DirectCast(sender, Control).Text
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm totally new in VB.NET. This code helps me too.It's clean and easier to understood for beginner. Thanks for your help! =D