# Remove 3 rows from selected item in ListBox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a `ListBox` which contains some data.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add("Set 1")
ListBox1.Items.Add("1.1")
ListBox1.Items.Add("1.2")
ListBox1.Items.Add("1.3")
```

- Set 1

  - 1.1
  - 1.2
  - 1.3
- Set 2

  - 2.1
  - 2.2
  - 2.3
- Set 3
- Set 4
- Set 1

  - 1.1
  - 1.2
  - 1.3
- Set 1

  - 1.1
  - 1.2
  - 1.3

Etc.

`Set 1` and `Set 2` contain 3 more sub-data while `Set 3` and `Set 4` do not have any sub-data. Once selected `Set 3` or `Set 4`, it will delete selected data.

```
' Remove Set 3 and Set 4 selected data
ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

Once user selected `Set 1`, it should be deleted whole `Set 1` include it's sub-data and same for `Set 2`. No matter user selected on `1/1.1/1.2/1.3` or `2/2.1/2.2/2.3`, the whole content of selected set should be deleted from the `ListBox`. So far I have done this:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Select Case ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
            Case "Set 1"
                For i = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    For teller = 0 To 2
                        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
                    Next
                Next
            Case "Set 2"
                ' Etc
            Case Else
                ' Remove Set 3 and Set 4 selected data
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am confused.  A ListBox doesnt have subitems or sets, are they simply items for which the data is related to some parent thing?  Are you simply adding text or objects to the listbox?

Comment: @Plutonix Those data in listbox are simply added by ListBox1.Items.Add which are from button Set 1/2/3/4

Comment: You need to look into [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Neolisk Can u further explain what should I do? I just started to learn VB in few days ago.

Comment: You could start by clicking the link @Neolisk provided.

Comment: @KenWhite: Thanks. Also [this example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview).

Comment: @Neolisk, Is it possible to total up the value in my treeview?
eg: set 1 ($3) , Set 2 ($4) and etc to display at my lblTotal(label)?

Comment: @LeeLasc You need to change your way of thinking. Business object should be separate from its display. Treeview is a display control. It does not matter if you use it or your list box - totaling should work the same. You should keep a reference to you business object at form level. You will then communicate with it directly, bypassing any UI representation. Business object = "processing logic" here.

Comment: @Neolisk I give myself this project as my own learning purposes&interest to give me more better understanding in VB and I'm not in any IT related field. I got your point but not sure how to do it. I will give it a try, thanks for your advise! Appreciated much :) I just figured out solution for my this problem although it is not logic to do it in business object. After I done research on treeview, I feel that it is really much easier than list box to do it.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to put the answer in it, but [vote and choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or [add your own](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim count As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex`

```
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Select Case Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.SubString(0, 1)                
            Case "Set 1"
                For i = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    For teller = 0 To 1
                        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(count)
                    Next
                Next
            Case Else
                MsgBox("Please select set to delete!")
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

despite the fact that you should use a tree for displaying subitems here is a solution for your problem

**EDIT**: OK i adjusted this to your naming and this should work. Just put it on your Button5 Click Event. Your comment states otherwise maybe explain a little further?

```
    Dim mainitemList As New List(Of String)
    Dim subitemList As New List(Of String)
    Dim currentMain As String

    For Each selItem As String In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        If Not selItem.Contains(".") Then
            mainitemList.Add(selItem)

            currentMain = selItem.Replace("Set ", String.Empty)

            For Each lbSubItems As String In ListBox1.Items
                If lbSubItems.Contains(currentMain & ".") Then
                    subitemList.Add(lbSubItems)
                End If
            Next
        Else
            subitemList.Add(selItem)
        End If
    Next

    For Each subItem As String In subitemList
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(subItem)
    Next

    For Each mainItem As String In mainitemList
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(mainItem)
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this answer is quite complicated for me.  Actually my form is almost similar like this but not. [Idle_Mind sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27630545/2718651)

My form1 actually is selecting which set(1,2,3,4) and it will go to form2. In the form2, I need to select less ice,more ice and etc and pass the value into form1.listbox.

Comment: if your listbox items naming is Set 1.1/1.2/1.3 and so on this will work. If you need something else then i may have misunderstood your problem

Comment: I got your point, I feel it is more easier if I use treeview. I figure out how to do with that already although it seems like no logic. Thanks very much! =D